# Multiple environments in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, environment

I've got an Azure Cosmos DB that I'm using when developing my app. Now that a simple version of the app is ready, I'd like to create a staging and production environment for it. No problems creating new environments for the app by using Azure App Service Slots, but I'm not sure about Cosmos DB. How should I do that? Should I create a new database for each environment? Or are there slots for databases.

Answer (score 0):

There is not slots for Cosmos DB. You'll need to manage the different resources yourself. You can use different Databases to achieve this purpose, if you need different resources for staging and production. The only issue with using the same database account is that replication is at the database account level, so if you don't need the extra regions/etc. for staging, you might want to split them into different Database Account to save some money.